# In The Entity Framework how can I create convention to set default value for DateTime

Tags: entity-framework

I can set a default value on a DateTime2 column via changing the default value in the DB Migration:

```
created_on = c.DateTime(nullable: false, precision: 7, storeType: "datetime2", defaultValueSql: "SYSUTCDATETIME()"),
```

However, I would like to do this via a convention or some other way where I can avoid setting this for every table and every field.  For example, any property that is a date and is not nullable, should have the defaultValueSql = SYSUTCDATETIME() applied.

Comment: You will need to wait until EF7 is available: https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2929682-support-database-default-values-in-code-first